# Is it possible to open a word document in Rad Editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radeditor

I am new to use rad editor and I want to open word document in Rad Editor for edit and save back. it is possible to open word document in rad editor and save back to file using rad Editor.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: No, I am new to use rad editor and no any idea for do this

Comment: Nope, it's intended to give you clean, xhtml output whilst giving the user a familiar looking environment in which they can author their content. It does have export to RTF and PDF which could be useful but there's no facility to load up a word document, edit it inline, and save it back again. You should look at the OpenXML libraries to manipulate word documents.

Answer (score 1):

Since Q2 2014, it is possible to load a Word document in RadEditor. You can see how in this help article: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-import-export-to-word.html

Import DOCX

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("DocxEditor.docx"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        RadEditor1.LoadDocxContent(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Import RTF

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("RtfEditor.rtf"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        RadEditor1.LoadRtfContent(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you convert Doc file into html page

[try this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveas.aspx) also try this link [Also here](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/430382-convert-word-doc-html)

then that html page code is assign to that rad control

RadControl.Text = (html page code)

Comment: RadEditorInstance.Content is the property you should use

Comment: ..., because the Text property will load the content as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, you can use the `LoadDocxContent` method of the `RadEditor` class.

```
string path = "path to your Word document";

using (var fs = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    ms.SetLength(fs.Length);
    fs.Read(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fs.Length);
    RadEditor1.LoadDocxContent(ms);
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately this is not possible.
What you can do though is save the word files in rtf format and try loading them in the editor

Check the following link which should really help you

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/editor/is-it-possible-to-open-a-word-document-in-rad-editor.aspx